# Problems when create a project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I made a new project in android studio, when this finally was created in the main activity marked some errors, one of those errors is the AppCpmátActivity, i know that this is because I don't have the compile exported, but I have it exported in my Build.Gradle (Module App). but when i want to sync the gradle, this show me the next errors

[image: those errors]

this is my build.gradle (Module: App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "demontechsystemsecurity.trackingtool"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I don't know what's really the problem because I opt by downloading all the sdk tools and

this is the build.gradle (Project: Project Name)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

if I add in the repositories `google()` it showme this

[image: this error]

but is the same if I click over `Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project` this doesn't make any action

Comment: And did you try installing like the solution is suggesting?

Comment: yup but this doens't make anything, I click over  install repository and sync project but don't make something

Comment: Can you show the contents of the project's build.gradle. Your gradle version will be there. It will help solve the problem

Comment: @ArunShankar I add more, i don't know if you reffer to that

Comment: Its surprising, I copy pasted your code and its working just fine. I think you have to install all the required build tools, dependencies and it should just work. You can also exit Studio and try to create another new project.

Comment: well I just uninstall and install like 6 times my Andorid Studio and the problem persist, i just download all in my SDK Tools and this doesn't get solved

Answer (score 0):

Add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```